# Nginx reverse proxy to apache gives timeout if you dont put in a trailing slash

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have got nginx to reverse proxy any requests to dev.example.com to apache. It all works fine, and I installed wordpress on the url "dev.example.com/wordpress/". The weird thing is that if you type in the url "dev.exmaple.com/wordpress" you get a connection timed out error, but if you type in "dev.exmaple.com/wordpress/" **with the trailing slash**, it connects fine. Why does it do this?

edit: sorry here is the nginx config

```
server{
    server_name dev.example.com;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8078;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

            client_max_body_size       10m;
            client_body_buffer_size    128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout      90;
            proxy_send_timeout         90;
            proxy_read_timeout         90;

            proxy_buffer_size          4k;
            proxy_buffers              4 32k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }
}
```

I copied most of that from somewhere, not sure where...

for apache, all I did was change

```
NameVirtualHost *:8078
Listen 8078
```

in the ports.conf file.

I also editied sites-available/default and put

```
<VirtualHost *:8078>
```

on the top instead of

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

This is all on ec2 (ubuntu).

Comment: Show you nginx config.

Comment: Please post your Apache and nginx configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

Without the trailing slash you are trying to be redirected, you should set a [proxy_redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect) sentence to resolve the issue. For example:

proxy_redirect http://localhost:8078/ http://dev.example.com/